# How to downgrade to Platformio3

Tags: homebrew, platformio

How can I install an old version of PlatformIO?
E.g. installing Platformio3.6.7 on macosx

I tried via homebrew

```
brew install platformio@3.6.7
Error: No available formula with the name "platformio@3.6.7"
```

without luck

```
brew search platformio
platformio
```

it seems that homebrew has only the latest version 4

```
brew info platformio
platformio: stable 4.3.3
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it worked the following.

**uninstall current homebrew platformio**:

```
brew uninstall platformio
```

**install it with python2.7 pip** (python3 not supported)

```
pip install -U "platformio<4"
```

OR (using python command to ensure version):

```
python2.7 -m pip install -U "platformio<4" --user
```

---

checking installed version:

```
python2.7 -m platformio --version
PlatformIO, version 3.6.7
```

running commands:

```
python2.7 -m platformio run ...
```